# Branch iOS 8 Universal link issue

Tags: ios, branch.io, ios-universal-links

Branch universal link working in 9.3 device with live app but not working in iOS 8 device live and test app.In iOS 8 device when i clicking a universal link it redirect through Safari.

Answer (score 5):

Universal Linking is a new feature that only works in iOS 9+. For iOS 8, you'll need to use old-fashioned URL schemes.

Since Universal Links don't work everywhere even in iOS 9, you'd want URL scheme links anyway as a fallback. You might try a service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I work there) to handle all of these different permutations!

Answer (score 1):

Universal links were introduced in iOS 9, so obviously they don't work in iOS 8.